# pass TextBox value to variable within SUB

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form (named DateForm) that contains a textbox (named txt_AsOfDate), which displays a date value.

I have a separate SUB which has the following code:

```
Sub Test()


    Dim AsOfDate As String
    AsOfDate = txt_AsOfDate.Text

    MsgBox (AsOfDate)

End Sub
```

When running it, I get the following error:

```
Run-time error '424': Object required
```

What is going on? I tried loading the DateForm at the beginning of the SUB, and also tried assigning the value by further defining the object schema like below, but no luck. What am I doing wrong?

```
AsOfDate = DateForm.txt_AsOfDate.Value
```

Comment: There must be something missing here.  It works for me.  What line does the error get thrown on?

Comment: @roryap - It is getting thrown on this line: `AsOfDate = txt_AsOfDate.Text`. I want to mention that the textbox is getting populated by a query running against one of the tables in the Access solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing `txt_AsOfDate.Text` with `Form_DateForm.txt_AsOfDate.Text`.  Referring to a control directly in code by its name only works in the form, whereas I'm guessing this code is in a separate module.

In order to catch things like this, add `Option Explicit` to the top of your code modules.  This forces the compiler to notify you if there is a variable being used which wasn't first declared with `Dim`.